# Struts : How to iterate until a value is reached

Tags: java, struts2

I am calculating the number of pages in a search screen in an Action class. I need to iterate from 1 to  to display page numbers with links, and I can't find a way to do this with `<s:iterator>`

The java equivalent code will be, 
Please let me know where there is a way to achieve this in a JSP with struts 2.0 tags.

```
    for ( int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++ ) {
        // print page no
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/iterator.html

Use the `"begin"` and `"end"` attributes of the `<s:iterator>` tag for easy-to-read loops.

You can also play OGNL games, like:

```
<s:iterator status="stat" value="(5).{ #this }">
```

which will loop five times.

Values can come from an action property as normal.

Comment: Thank you. I am thinking of using the OGNL construct

Answer (score 1):

For using a look in the JSP side of your S2 application you have the way to use Struts2 [Iterator tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/iterator.html).

This iterator tag take a collection as input source of iteration. If you are using S2 version 2.1.7 or higher, you can take the advantage of begin, end and step attributes.All you need to have a collection in your Action class with its getter and setters and in your JP you have to do something like

```
<s:iterator value="days">
  <p>day is: <s:property/></p>
</s:iterator>
```

For details refer to the tag documentation

- [iterator](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/iterator.html)

You are free to use S2 if tag inside the iterator tag to place various conditions as per your requirements

- [If Tag Refrence](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/if.html)

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I forgot to mention that we are using struts 2.0 here. I was thinking of generating a collection as in your example, but thought there may be a better way of doing similar to for loop.

Comment: on the JSP side, using S2 iterator tag is best way to use.you can use `if` tag to place your conditional logic.